# fetching rows with certain conditions and data framing them

Tags: pandas

Current Dataframe :

```
key        status           score
A           initial            2
A           in-between         3
A           intermediate       6
A           pre-final          2
A           final              3
B           initial            1
B           intermediate       7
B           final              8
```

I am looking to get two seperate dataframe , dataframe 1 should only include rows before the status is intermediate and dataframe 2 should only include rows after the status is intermediate

Expected Dataframes :

Dataframe 1 :

```
   key        status           score
    A           initial            2
    A           in-between         3
    B           initial            1
```

Dataframe 2 :

```
key        status           score
A           pre-final          2
A           final              3
B           final              8
```

Tried :

```
cond = df.status.eq("intermediate")
mask = cond.groupby(df.key).cummax().shift(fill_value=False)
dataframe_1 = df[~mask]
dataframe_2 = df[mask]
```

with this i am not getting the required dataframes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`groupby.cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummin.html) to set all rows from "intermediate" to False, then use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m1 = df['status'].ne('intermediate')
m2 = m1.groupby(df['key']).cummin()

dataframe_1 = df[m2]
#   key      status  score
# 0   A     initial      2
# 1   A  in-between      3
# 5   B     initial      1

dataframe_2 = df[m1 & ~m2]
#   key        status  score
# 3   A     pre-final      2
# 4   A         final      3
# 7   B         final      8
```

Comment: cummin  beautiful usage！

Answer (score 0):

Remove `shift` for first mask and for second filter out `intermediate` values:

```
cond = df.status.eq("intermediate")
mask = cond.groupby(df.key).cummax()

dataframe_1 = df[~mask]
print (dataframe_1)
  key      status  score
0   A     initial      2
1   A  in-between      3
5   B     initial      1

dataframe_2 = df[mask & ~cond]
print (dataframe_2)
  key     status  score
3   A  pre-final      2
4   A      final      3
7   B      final      8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.assign(col2=dd.status.isin(['intermediate']).cumsum())\
        .query("status!='intermediate'")

df1.groupby('key').apply(function1)\
    .reset_index(drop=True).groupby('col2').apply(lambda dd:print(dd.iloc[:,:3]))


key      status  score
0   A     initial      2
1   A  in-between      3
4   B     initial      1

  key     status  score
2   A  pre-final      2
3   A      final      3
5   B      final      8
```